# Triggers for multiple rows at once

Tags: mysql, trigger

So I have these three tables. The orders table is list of orders existed, while the order details consist of items that is in an order (because 1 order can have more than one catalog). I'm using mysql

Cust_order

| Order_id | Name | Email | Shipping_Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bryan | bryan@gmail.com | Shiped |

Order_item

| Od_id | Order_id | Catalog_id | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 2. | 1 | 2 | 5 |

Inventory

| Catalog_id | quantityInStock |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 10 |

I want to create a trigger that if the shipping_status in orders table is 'shipped', then it will update the stock in inventory.

I've created this trigger

```
create trigger update_inventory
after update on cust_order
for each row 
begin
if new.shipping_status="Shipped" then
update inventory 
set inStock = inStock - (select quantity from order_item where order_id=new.order_id)
where catalog_id in (select catalog_id from order_item where order_id=new.order_id);
end if;
end;
//
```

But it doesn't work and turns #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

How to create trigger that updates multiple row at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER update_inventory
AFTER UPDATE ON cust_order
FOR EACH ROW 
UPDATE inventory 
JOIN order_item USING (catalog_id)
SET inventory.quantityInStock = inventory.quantityInStock - order_item.quantity
WHERE cust_order.order_id = NEW.order_id
  AND NEW.shipping_status = 'Shipped';
```

The query needs `order_item (order_id, catalog_id)` to be defined as UNIQUE in the table structure. If not then you must use aggregating subquery instead of single table in `JOIN order_item`.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are rather limited in what they can do.

Instead, write a Stored Procedure to encapsulate the set of operations that you need to perform "atomically".  And be sure to put them in a "transaction".

Comment: I do not see the limitation which prevents the trigger usage - except incorrect logic during its creation.